# Issue with my Logic app - Send-email-with-formatted-incident-report

Tags: azure-sentinel

I have a logic app that is build in from Microsoft for sentinel. Every time an alert gets generated in sentinel , it gets sent to the dynamic crm . But it is triggering twice. What have i done wrong? It was all okay up until yesterday.